# Rewrite Rules only work with specific User Agent?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a big problem that causes my whole web root to shut down (505 Internal Error) where every domain is affected, even if the htaccess file is only in one directory. My file structure is organized this way, so every domain is a seperate folder:

```
    web root
    -- [domainA]
       (domainA files like the .htaccess file)
    -- [domainB]
    -- [domainC]
    (web root files)
```

I want to implement my routing system and everything works fine on my localhost with this `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

However, I'm testing for hours to make my routing work on my remote server with the same `.htaccess` code. I uploaded the file and it also works when I'm at the main directory like `www.domainA.com`.

BUT every link I'm clicking on my website like `www.domainA.com/signup` leads to an `505 Internal Server Error`. The whole domain isn't even responding for a long time. I have to delete the `.htaccess` file from my remote server and maybe after 15-30 minutes it's reachable again. That also makes this problem so difficult to debug. Also my **whole** web root seems to be affected since all other domains aren't reachable, too (even if the `.htaccess` file is only located in the seperate domain folder like in `[domainA]`).

Then I tried to apply my rule only on a specific user agent named `fake-user`:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^fake-user$
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

This way it surprisingly works like on localhost and I don't get why. Obviously I don't want to limit my audience to user agents named `fake-user` to interact with my website. So currently all other users would "crash" my website. I hope to get some explanations what could cause this and how to fix this problem to make it work like on my localhost for all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it could be recursion, try replacing your rule with this:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php$). index.php [NS,L]
```

which only rewrites when it's different.